# Contained class requiring information from another contained class

Tags: c++, oop

If I have a contained class which has a method that require information from a different contained class within the same container instance, how can I do that? Do I pass a reference to the container into A? (I'm also a little unsure how to do that) Or do I call A's method from the container since it contains both A and B?

I'm new to C++ and OOP so I'm not sure if what I'm doing will be breaking some rules of OOP.

```
class Container {
  private:
    A a;
    B b;
}

class A {
  public:
    int bar() {
      //How do I get b.foo here?
    }
}

class B {
  public:
   int foo;
}
```

Comment: Why do the contained classes need to access each other in the first place? Can you describe what `A` and `B` really are?

Comment: "Do I pass a reference to the container into A?" Yes, basically that. With that said, what is the original problem you need to solve? This feels like a problem more with the design than the implementation. Working around bad design in code is unfortunately too common, but it shouldn't happen.

Comment: This sounds like an XY-Problem.  What are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: If I have a container `Game` that holds `Player` and `Enemy`. The damage `Player` deals to `Enemy` requires the `Enemy`'s defense stat.

Comment: @I._.I How does the `Player` object know that an `Enemy` object exists? Whatever tells the `Player` object that there is an `Enemy` to damage should be able to provide the necessary reference.

Comment: I see, so in that case, should `Game` be the one to call all the methods since it holds everything?

Comment: Why not consider this? Before creating damage, check `Enemy`’s defense stat? This will do: `int bar(B&);`, with this, I don’t even see why they are both in one `class Container`. Maybe there are other reasons.

Comment: imho one of the most important rules of OO is: "Can someone else do that?". Why does a player need to know the enemy stats to determine the damge they make? The less a class does the better. How about this: An enemy uses some weapon or whatever, to do certain `amount` of certain `damage_type`. That damge is then applied to an enemy where their defense etc is considered. Neither the Player nor the enemy need to know anything about each other. I agree with others, that this is a question about design that would need more details than currently provided in the question

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions. Can anyone suggest some material I read to learn more about these design decisions?